# SQL Loop Distinct Values for Use in Calculated Columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to do something in SQL here. I have a product type, lets call it "Food" and I have a table with names of stores, product types, and product names, let's call the stores, "Red, Blue, Green". I want to run a query that finds every store in which Product Type "Food" was sold.

So something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Stores] 
FROM dbo.SalesTable 
WHERE [Product Type] = 'Food'
```

Then I want to use each distinct store name in a loop, to populate calculated columns telling me the sales numbers of each product type in the individual stores. The actual `Product Type` could be many things and each would have a unique list of stores.  So I will probably declare the VARCHAR variable for use in the query.

Basically I think column A would be product Names for the product type used, and columns 2 through X would be the sales of each product at each store. If there were 5 stores then those calculations would sit in columns 2 through 6.

I just have no experience using loops in SQL and hopefully somebody can help out.  Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is going to be your key here.

```
SELECT [Product Type], Stores, SUM(SalesTable.column1), COUNT(SalesTable.column2) ...
FROM SalesTable
GROUP BY [Product Type], Stores
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Wow. I have no idea how this functionally works.  Would this get messed up if I had for instance another column in there that was more or less the sum of all the stores? The columns would look like Product Type, Product Name, Sum of all Purchased Quantities, Sum of quantity at store 1, Sum of quantity at store 2......store n  ?

Comment: If that's the case you'd have to do something like 
SUM(CASE WHEN Stores = 'Store1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Store1Count, SUM(CASE WHEN Stores = 'Store2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Store2Count.... etc.]